# How to find the set of the unitization of suspension $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, then the suspension $SA$ is given by

$SA=\{f\in C(\Bbb T,A):f(1)=0\}$.

I saw the following conclusions from Olsen's book (page 136)
Denote the unitization of $SA$ by $\tilde{SA}$, then

$\tilde{SA}=\{f\in C(\Bbb T,A^+):f(1)=\lambda \in \Bbb C,\pi_{\Bbb C}f(z)=\lambda,\forall  z \in \Bbb T\}$.

How to verify the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define 
$$\varphi:\tilde{SA}\to\{f\in C(\mathcal T,\tilde A):f(1)=\lambda,\pi_\mathbb Cf(z)=\lambda\}$$
by
$$(\varphi(f,\lambda))(z)=(f(z),\lambda)$$
for $f\in SA$, $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.  Show that this map is a $*$-isomorphism.

Comment: How to define the involution of f ? Is the following definition correct? $f^*(z)=(f(z))^*$?

Answer (score 0):

Prove that 
$$
 \widetilde {SA} / SA \to \mathbb C : [f] \mapsto f(1) 
$$
is an isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by compute ? What is wrong with Wegge-Olsens description ?